# Neural Network training with Maximum Likelihood

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, maximum-likelihood

Is it possible to train a neural network (that outputs mean and standard deviation) with maximum likelihood?

What does the setup look like and is there any tool supporting it?

Comment: Thanks for the response. After some review and research, I think what I need to do is to construct a NN from scratch that takes some inputs and outputs mean and standard deviation, with weights and bias as parameters. Then calibrate those parameters in a MLE.

Comment: Are you saying your objective function is an MLE?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, I think this question can be formulated as a function approximation problem. Where we are approximate the `mean` and `standard deviation` function with a Neural Network.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565115/approximating-function-with-neural-network) is a useful reference.

To build such a neural network, we need to generate data for training. Let's assume your network has 100 inputs. We can do following steps to generate the training data.

1. Randomly generate 100 numbers N times.
2. For each time, calculate expected outcome (mean and standard deviation)
3. Put these N numbers with expected outcome to neural network for training.

Note, the relationship with Maximize likelihood can be described as follows: we can prove the empirical mean and empirical standard deviation is the MLE estimation of the true parameters (Assuming Gaussian Distribution).

Comment: Thanks.In my problem, I am trying to use NN to translate a list of inputs into a normal distribution (characterized by mean and std)  that has maximum likelihood for an observed value.